# how to setup pimcore on vps server via docker compose yml

Tags: docker, web-server, vps, cms

I am really exhausted to get pimcore running on my vps server.

I tried several OS like Unbuntu 18 / 20 or CentOS 7. I tried to install pimcore via composer. But there I always get some errors, when I tried to fix them, they lead to some more.

The best way for me is with the docker-compose.yml. I managed to install pimcore with that and I am able to run the containers described here : https://github.com/pimcore/skeleton/tree/10.2

After the installation of pimcore I pointed the vhost on my-project/public. There is the index.php Now I get this error

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for db failed: Name or service not known

I really tried to set up the db host in the docker-compose.yml and also in the .env file. But still, it did not work.

Now I stopped the container and was surprised that on my domain the error still exists, even without the running containers.

Do I need to tell my VPS that it has to take the docker-compose.yml database? Or are there any other things I need to do, to get pimcore running on my server via docker-compose? I just used the skeleton version provided from pimcore/github .

I really need your help.

this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
    redis:
        image: redis:alpine
        command: [ redis-server, --maxmemory 128mb, --maxmemory-policy volatile-lru, --save "" ]

    db:
        image: mariadb:10.7
        working_dir: /application
        command: [mysqld, --character-set-server=utf8mb4, --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci, --innodb-file-per-table=1]
        volumes:
            - pimcore-database:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ROOT
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
            - MYSQL_USER=user
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pw

    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html:ro
            - ./.docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
        depends_on:
            - php

    php:
        user: '1000:1000' # set to your uid:gid
        image: pimcore/pimcore:php8.1-debug-latest
        environment:
            COMPOSER_HOME: /var/www/html
            PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=localhost
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html

    supervisord:
        user: '1000:1000' # set to your uid:gid
        image: pimcore/pimcore:php8.1-supervisord-latest
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
            - ./.docker/supervisord.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/pimcore.conf:ro

volumes:
    pimcore-database:
```

and this is my config/config.yaml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: 'local/' }


pimcore:

# IMPORTANT Notice!
# Following there are only some examples listed, for a full list of possible options, please run the following command:
# ./bin/console debug:config pimcore
# you can also filter them by path, eg.
# ./bin/console debug:config pimcore assets
# or even more specific:
# ./bin/console debug:config pimcore assets.image


#### TRANSLATIONS
#    translations:
#        case_insensitive: true

#### FEATURE FLAGS
#    flags:
#        zend_date: true

#### CLASS OVERRIDES EXAMPLES
#    models:
#        class_overrides:
#            'Pimcore\Model\DataObject\News': 'App\Model\DataObject\News'
#            'Pimcore\Model\DataObject\News\Listing': 'App\Model\DataObject\News\Listing'
#            'Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Folder': 'App\Model\DataObject\Folder'
#            'Pimcore\Model\Asset\Folder': 'App\Model\Asset\Folder'
#            'Pimcore\Model\Asset\Image': 'App\Model\Asset\Image'
#            'Pimcore\Model\Document\Page': 'App\Model\Document\Page'
#            'Pimcore\Model\Document\Link': 'App\Model\Document\Link'
#            'Pimcore\Model\Document\Listing': 'App\Model\Document\Listing'


#### CUSTOM DOCUMENT EDITABLES
#    documents:
#        allow_trailing_slash: 'yes'
#        generate_preview: false
#        tags:
#            map:
#                markdown: \App\Model\Document\Tag\Markdown


#### CUSTOM OBJECT DATA TYPES
#    objects:
#        class_definitions:
#            data:
#                map:
#                  myDataType: \App\Model\DataObject\Data\MyDataType


#### ASSET CUSTOM SETTINGS
#    assets:
#        icc_rgb_profile: ''
#        icc_cmyk_profile: ''
#        versions:
#            use_hardlinks: false
#        image:
#            low_quality_image_preview:
#                enabled: false
#                generator: imagick
#            thumbnails:
#                webp_auto_support: false


#### SYSTEM SETTINGS

#    general:
#        timezone: Europe/Berlin
#        path_variable: ''
#        instance_identifier: ''
#    services:
#        google:
#            client_id: 738936983.apps.googleusercontent.com
#            email: 73893983@developer.gserviceaccount.com
#            simple_api_key: AIzaSyCo9Wj49hW2WgOju4iMYNTvdcBxmyQ8
#            browser_api_key: AIzaSyBJX16kWAmU1amzp2iKqAfumbcoQQ
#    full_page_cache:
#        enabled: false
#        lifetime: null
#        exclude_cookie: ''
#        exclude_patterns: ''
#    httpclient:
#        adapter: Socket # use 'Proxy' for custom proxy configuration
#        proxy_host: ''
#        proxy_port: ''
#        proxy_user: ''
#        proxy_pass: ''
#    email:
#        sender:
#            name: 'Pimcore Demo'
#            email: demo@pimcore.com
#        return:
#            name: ''
#            email: ''
#    newsletter:
#        use_specific: false # set true to use the following options for newsletter delivery
#        sender:
#            name: ''
#            email: ''
#        return:
#            name: ''
#            email: ''

#    applicationlog:
#        mail_notification:
#            send_log_summary: false
#            filter_priority: null
#            mail_receiver: ''
#        archive_treshold: '30'
#        archive_alternative_database: ''

#### SYMFONY OVERRIDES
framework:

#### DEFINE LOCATION OF MANIFEST WHEN WORKING WITH SYMFONY ENCORE
#    assets:
#        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'

#### USE CUSTOM CACHE POOL
#    cache:
#        pools:
#            pimcore.cache.pool:
#                public: true
#                tags: true
#                default_lifetime: 31536000  # 1 year
#                adapter: pimcore.cache.adapter.redis_tag_aware
#                provider: 'redis://localhost' # Redis DNS, see: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/redis_adapter.html#configure-the-connection

#### USE SESSION HANDLER CONFIGURED IN php.ini
#    session:
#        handler_id: null

#### SYMFONY MAILER TRANSPORTS
#    mailer:
#        transports:
#            main: smtp://user:pass@smtp.example.com:port
#            pimcore_newsletter: smtp://user:pass@smtp.example.com:port
```

It is in config/local/database.yaml ?

```
# imports:
#     - { resource: 'local/' }

parameters:
    database_host: 'pimcoredb'
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: 'db'
    database_user: 'user'
    database_password: 'pw'

pimcore:
```

Comment: PHP can't find the address you provided for the database. Please provide your config file and your docker-compose.yml

Comment: where is your pimcore database configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Your database container is called `db`, but you configured pimcore to connect to a host named `pimcoredb`.

Change your db config to connect to `db` instead.

```yaml
parameters:
  database_host: 'db'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the same error occurs. Docker Containers are running well.